# Prisma/ User `postgres` was denied access on the database `practice.public`

Tags: prisma

I'm quite new to Prisma, so if I overlook something basic, please forgive me.

I was running postgreSQL DB on a docker container and tried `npx prisma migrate dev` from local.
However, the following error occurred:

```
Error: P1010: User `postgres` was denied access on the database `practice.public`
```

my docker-compose.yml file and .env file were the followings:

```
// docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: practice
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
```

```
// .env
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/practice?schema=public"
```

I tried everything I could come up with, and **accidentally found a solution**.
First, I checked the username of my host computer.

```
echo $USER
>myusername
```

Then put the username into the DATABASE_URL in .env file, instead of the POSTGRES_USER I defined in docker-compose.yml.

```
// .env
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://myusername:postgres@localhost:5432/practice?schema=public"
```

`npx prisma dev migrate` worked for some reason. Congrats.
But I haven't the least idea of why it worked……

If you shed some lights on it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: atleast for me just use the
echo $USER and it works